# How can I hide the pager in Kendo UI Grid when autoBind is set to false?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid that has the "auto-bind" property set to false. I have also set the "pageable.alwaysVisible" property to false to hide the grid's pager when it's not needed.

The problem I'm having is that because the grid is not data bound when it first loads, the "alwaysVisible" property does not work and the pager is shown. At this stage I would expect the pager to be hidden as there is no data to be paged.

Is there anyway I can hide the pager on first load when the grid is not data bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like what you want is available out-of-the-box, but you could achieve it using a bit of CSS. This is probably a better approach than my previous answer, which in essence triggered the grid to bind itself anyway. How about hiding the pager initially until the grid is eventually bound, at which point it takes over management of the pager visibility?

```
<style>
  #grid>.k-pager-wrap.k-grid-pager {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div id="grid"></div>
<button onclick="javascript:$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read()">Refresh</button>
<script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "productName" },
      { field: "category" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
      { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
      { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
      { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
    ],
    pageable: {
      pageSize: 3,
      alwaysVisible: false
    },
    autoBind: false
  });
</script>
```

Example here: https://dojo.telerik.com/EBaZAjAc

Comment: This seems to be the missing link, and I think this makes "alwaysVisible" behave as it should. Thanks for taking the time to come back with anther solution!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a quirk of the grid when it doesn't know that it has no data yet. Perhaps you could try pushing "no data" into your datasource in the first instance? The following snippet demonstrates your problem; un-commenting the last line fixes it:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            { field: "productName" },
            { field: "category" }
        ],
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource(),
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 5,
            alwaysVisible: false
        },
        autoBind: false,
    });
    //$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([]);
</script>
```

Example here: https://dojo.telerik.com/OZAXugOt

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
dataBound: function(e){
if(e.sender.dataSource.total() <= e.sender.dataSource.pageSize()){
  e.sender.pager.element.hide();
} else {
  e.sender.pager.element.show();
}
```

Take a look at this example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/OhEDo